# Node http client reconnect after connection timeout

Tags: node.js, timeout, icecast, internet-radio, audiostreamer

I've been using a package called [icy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icy) that uses the Http Client from Node v8.11.3.

I'm connecting to a streamer Icecast server with continuous audio.

The code looks like the following:

```
icy.get(url, (res) => {

  res.on('end', (e) => console.log('connection ends')); // end of connection
  res.on('metadata' => () => {...}); // metadata handler
}
```

**The problem comes when the Icecast server restarts or times out.**

I want the function to try to reconnect after timeout but haven't found an option to it in the docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the error event and the finish of the stream event:

```
const icy = require('icy');

var url = 'http://ice4.lagrosseradio.info/lagrosseradio-metal-024.mp3';

(function play() {
    this.count = 0
    this.timeout

    function restart(error) {
        this.count++;
        console.error(this.count + ' reconnect...');
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(play, 100);
    }

    const client = icy.get(url, function(res) {
        res.on('metadata', function(metadata) {
            console.log(icy.parse(metadata));
        });
        client.on('close', function(error) {
            restart(error);
        });
    });
    client.on('error', function(error) {
        restart(error);
    });
})();
```

Comment: That's great but I'm using  Node v8.11.3. Unfortunately, using finished() is not an option since it was included on Node v10.0.0. I'm using res.on('end', callback). Will try to check if that could be a replacement. Thanks!

Comment: Then instead finished use Event: 'close' (see fix)